# Correct tag(s) for Mac OS Classic (version 9 and earlier) questions

Tags: discussion, tags

I ran into a question involving Mac OS 9: [How do I find the MAC address in Mac OS 9?](https://superuser.com/questions/383961/how-do-i-find-the-mac-address-in-mac-os-9)

How should questions involving legacy versions of Mac OS be tagged?  I'm not sure if Tom Wijsman's tagging is correct here.  Obviously, the [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) tag should not be used here as Mac OS X is not the same as Mac OS Classic.

Comment: not a Mac guy but [tag:mac-os] seems the right tag.

Comment: @Sathya: No, because most of its questions were OS X, it's deadly ambiguous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:** I removed the ambiguously [mac-os](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-os) tag and grouped classic stuff under [mac-os-classic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-os-classic).

---

I first came into this tag seeing a ton of [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) questions so I wrongly assumed [mac-os](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-os) meant [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) and it didn't came to my mind that `X` actually stands for 10+ here. So, then I went to tag them [mac-os-8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-os-8) and [mac-os-9](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-os-9). But, that was also messy.

**So, I went on to retag Mac hardware questions to [mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac), 0-9 to [mac-os-classic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-os-classic) and 10+ to [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx).**

The reason I wanted to get gone of the 10-15 questions in [mac-os](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-os) is because that tag is *ambiguous*, at least half of the questions were actually [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) questions which makes the tag less valuable.

The other thing that might be bothering is that [mac-os-classic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-os-classic) and [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) are inconsistently named, using [os-classic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/os-classic) might make no sense though. Using [mac-os-x](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-os-x) doesn't either, because then you are going to have issues having long tags like [mac-os-x-snow-leopard](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-os-x-snow-leopard).

*Note that I did most of this tagging before this meta question came, which mods allow us for tags that contain a very low amount of questions and that would make sense to retag. Glad DL catched my error.*